# Understanding the output of all_equal

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using `dplyr::all_equal` to try and find differences between datasets. I don't always understand the output when the datasets are not equal.

I've generated some small tibbles to try and tease out the meaning of the outputs by easy comparison between the tibbles, but the different outputs confuse me. I've looked at the documentation and it doesn't provide a satisfactory explanation for me, because there aren't any details explaining how the result explains differences besides positions. The examples in the documentation don't really cover this case either.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df1 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df2 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df3 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df4 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))

df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   value
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     3
#> 3     2
#> 4     4
df2
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   value
#>   <int>
#> 1     4
#> 2     0
#> 3     2
#> 4     4
df3
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   value
#>   <int>
#> 1     2
#> 2     2
#> 3     5
#> 4     2
df4
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   value
#>   <int>
#> 1     3
#> 2     2
#> 3     0
#> 4     4

all_equal(df1, df2)
#> [1] "Rows in x but not y: 1, 2. Rows in y but not x: 2. Rows with difference occurences in x and y: 4"
all_equal(df1, df4)
#> [1] "Rows in x but not y: 1. Rows in y but not x: 3. "
all_equal(df1, df3)
#> [1] "Rows in x but not y: 1, 2, 4. Rows in y but not x: 3. Rows with difference occurences in x and y: 3"
all_equal(df2, df3)
#> [1] "Rows in x but not y: 2, 1. Rows in y but not x: 3. Rows with difference occurences in x and y: 3"
all_equal(df2, df4)
#> [1] "Rows in y but not x: 1. Rows with difference occurences in x and y: 1"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

If someone were to ask me "How many observations are different between the two sets," based on the outputs above, my response would be the largest number of rows returned by "Rows in __ but not __: number". So, for instance, I would say:

"The number of observations between `df1` and `df3` that are different is 3."

Is this the right idea? Also, I don't know how to interpret the "Rows with difference occurences in x and y: number " portion, since in `all_equal(df1, df2)`, there are two differing observations between the sets but in row 4, the entries are the same.

Comment: I should have asked before answering. Does order matter to you when comparing datasets. Are you just looking for the # of common / unique elements? Are you open to answers that are not elucidating `all_equal`?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I am mostly looking to be able to say how many observations differ, and the position of those differences. `all_equal` provides that. But I am always open to other approaches! I suppose the crux of my question is interpreting  the "Rows with difference occurences in x and y" portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had to do something similar for double-data entry and used base R. Not exactly what you asked for, but I hope it helps. This can be done simpler on a case-by-case basis (e.g., `` mapply(`==`, df1, df2) ``), but I tailored my answer to scale for a lot of dataframes because you mention having 4. The code below tests each dataframe, row-by-row, for equality. Keep in mind, this solution is order-dependent (unlike `all_equal`) and if your dataframes do not have identical columns# / row# you will need to adapt this solution before it is viable. Good luck!!!

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df1 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df2 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df3 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))
df4 <- as_tibble(rpois(4, 2))

# Making a list of your dataframes 
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d"))

# Creating indices for the comparison (from df_list)
indices <- combn(seq_along(df_list), 2, simplify = F)

# Comparing all elements of the df_list
comparisons <- lapply(indices, function(x) mapply(`==`, df_list[x[1]], df_list[x[2]]))

# Cleaning up names
names(comparisons) <- sapply(indices, paste, collapse = " vs ")

head(comparisons, 2)
$`1 vs 2`
       df1
[1,] FALSE
[2,] FALSE
[3,]  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE

$`1 vs 3`
       df1
[1,] FALSE
[2,] FALSE
[3,] FALSE
[4,] FALSE

# Now, summarise it however you like, e.g.: Pct agreement
sapply(comparisons, mean)
1 vs 2 1 vs 3 1 vs 4 2 vs 3 2 vs 4 3 vs 4 
  0.50   0.00   0.25   0.00   0.25   0.25
```

EDIT: the above solution is similar to using `all_equal(df, df, ignore_col_order = FALSE, ignore_row_order = FALSE)`

Comment: This is handy approach. Thanks for providing this. My particular problem corresponds to translating code into R and then using said code to transform a data set. Having been stuck on how to get them identical for a while, I decided to determine how close my attempt was. Using `all_equal` provides a count of differing rows, allowing me to determine "good enough" and move on. But `mapply(`==`, ...)` will certainly be preferable when precision must be exact.

Comment: @ChrisAguilar, I see! It looks like you could pass a custom function to `Map` or `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` to get the info you want. A combo of `union` and `intersect` should get the you exactly what you want. If you clarify your exact output I could add an edit if it is helpful.